# Drive Mappings Erratically appearing/disappearing - Windows Ent Domain

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, hard-drive

We are having a very strange issue!

Windows 2003/2008 Domain (2003 DCs / 2008 File Servers)
Mixed Endpoint Environment - Win XP SP3 / Win7 Ent
1300 Users over several sites within a single domain

Users are experiencing an issue that their drive mappings might or might not show.  This can happen with a full restart or log off/on and can be one or more drives.

Most users have 3 or 4 mapped drives PLUS their home mapped drive.

We use GPO for the mapped drives.

A test will show the drive mapping, however after a restart some might not be there.

UNC to the drive paths works

Wait On Network GPO is applied

Running RSOP / GPResult shows that the drive mapping policy has been applied....but not showing.

Net Use shows the same as within My Computer

Disconnecting a drive or Deleting using Net Use makes no difference on if or if not the drive will be picked up upon next login

When the drive is not showing Netstat -a shows no connection (which would be expected)

Running a shortcut from a user’s desktop that points to a drive mapping which isn't showing automatically works and the drive mapping then shows in My Computer etc.

I cannot emphasise enough that this issue is VERY erratic.  No users or sites in particular suffer more or less.

Any help or assistance would be greatly received!